# Can we add webhook/trigger on when Admin uninstall SaaS app from Microsoft app source

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office-addins, outlook-restapi, appsource

we have created SaaS application for outlook calendar.
we have to delete database records when app got uninstalled from marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good ask.

If I understand correctly, you're asking for a delete notification on the application resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0).  Is that correct?

We don't currently support change notifications on the application resource today.  We have added this request to our backlog, but cannot provide an ETA for the work at this time (meaning it's currently further than 6 months out).